# How is a state function a sum of path function and state function?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

We know
H=U+pV
Where
H is the enthalpy (State function)
U is the internal energy (State function)
pV is the work done (Path function)\

How is it possible that a State function is the sum of a path and a state function. An intuitive explanation would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Which one do you think is a path function?

Comment: The work done.. @Chet Miller

Comment: I don't see the work done in your equation.  I see a term involving P and V at the two end points only, and this term depends only on the equation of state of the material (which is not path dependent).

Comment: There are an infinite number of process paths, with different values of heat and work, but with the same pressures and volumes at the same two thermodynamic equilibrium end points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$pV$ is not the work. It is an explicit state function.

The work done in a reversible transformation on the system is $-pdV$. Said in a more mathematical way, the problem of the exactness pertains to differential forms, not to functions.

Comment: What would be the suggested edit in this case?

Comment: @hawexrutile, I think I have answered. I do not see much to edit.

Comment: @hawexrutile Edits should not modify the original question in a way that makes ununderstandable the answers. I have rolled back the question to the original form.